# Unit Testing a Blazor RenderFragment element

Tags: c#, xunit, blazor

I've started to write a method for dynamically building a RenderFragment Element. As such I'm also trying to write Unit Tests alongside the method.

I'm starting with a very basic element and it fails. Here's the concrete method under test:

```
public RenderFragment buildFragment(string element, string elementContent, string[] attribute, string[] attributeContent)
    {
        RenderFragment content = builder => {
            builder.OpenElement(0, element);
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; attribute.Length - 1 >= i; ++i)
                {
                    builder.AddAttribute(0, attribute[i], attributeContent[i]);
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementContent))
            {
                builder.AddContent(0, elementContent);
            }
            builder.CloseElement();
        };

        return content;
    }
```

This is my first basic test against the method using xUnit:

```
public void BuildFragmentReturnsOneElement()
        {
            //Arrange
            RenderFragment fragment = builder =>
            {
                builder.OpenElement(0, "p");
                builder.CloseElement();
            };

            //Act
            RenderFragment result = _dynamicContentHelper.buildFragment("p", string.Empty, null, null);

            //Assert
            Assert.Same(fragment, result);
        }
```

The error I receive is:

> Message: Assert.Same() Failure
>   Expected: RenderFragment { Method = Void b__2_0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.RenderTree.RenderTreeBuilder), Target = <>c { } }
>   Actual:   RenderFragment { Method = Void b__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.RenderTree.RenderTreeBuilder), Target = <>c__DisplayClass0_0 { attribute = null, attributeContent = null, element = "p", elementContent = "" } }

I don't understand why **Target** on my **fragment** object is different from the **Target** on **result**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RenderFragment` is a Delegate method, so when you write code like this:

```
RenderFragment fragment = builder =>
            {
                builder.OpenElement(0, "p");
                builder.CloseElement();
            };
```

You are not creating a materialised artifact, but declaring a delegate that can be invoked.

The code `Assert.Same(fragment, result);` is therefore comparing two delegates, which are clearly not the same - they point to two different methods.

I believe you should investigate the "test" folder of the Blazor Source

[This section may help a lot](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a70f5312fb57fc3788e5af56a99e7b43761e195/src/Components/Blazor/Build/test/ChildContentRazorIntegrationTest.cs)

The technique they apply is to examine the frames of the RenderTree

```
// Act
var frames = GetRenderTree(component);

// Assert
Assert.Collection(
 frames,
 frame => AssertFrame.Component(frame, "Test.RenderChildContent", 2, 0),
 frame => AssertFrame.Attribute(frame, RenderTreeBuilder.ChildContent, 1),
 frame => AssertFrame.Markup(frame, "\n  <div></div>\n", 2));
```

[Also, this section with a TestRenderer](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a70f5312fb57fc3788e5af56a99e7b43761e195/src/Components/Blazor/Build/test/RazorIntegrationTestBase.cs) which has this code in it

```
protected RenderTreeFrame[] GetRenderTree(IComponent component)
        {
            var renderer = new TestRenderer();
            renderer.AttachComponent(component);
            component.SetParameters(ParameterCollection.Empty);
            return renderer.LatestBatchReferenceFrames;
        }
```

Have a look at how they do their tests as I cannot reproduce it all here, but those are the keys...

Comment: Looking at the link, this uses the namespace Microsoft.ASpNetCore.Components. I'm using Microsoft.ASpNetCore.Blazor. In general I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.2 and this doesn't have the Components namespace. From the link and your code snippet it looks as though the `GetRenderTree` method is key, but this isn't available to me anywhere. I'm also working with Blazor 0.7.0

Comment: The logic is the same, they just changed namespace. You can use GetFrames on your render fragment and then test those.

Comment: I cant see GetFrames anywhere, Can you confirm the namespace for this

Comment: I have updated the answer - the full method of testing is in the project I linked to on Github - it is too large to reproduce here, but the parts I highlighted should be enough to get you going.

Comment: The trouble I'm having is that in the latest link you have kindly offered, they use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace. This isn't available in 2.1.2. I notice they mention 2.0. I'll see if I can get anywhere by trying something as per your RenderTreeFrame example

Comment: Like I said before, they changed namespace, but the classes you are interested in will still exist in Blazor 0.7.0 - but in the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor

Comment: I figured out how to test my method. The code example above helped, but it wasn't exactly the same.

Comment: @bilpor What technique did you use for testing the fragment. I am trying to do something similar as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a very useful library for unit testing Blazor components named [bUnit](https://github.com/egil/bunit) library. The tests are very simple to be written. Here is an example of validating that a button click is working.

```
[Fact]
public void TestCounter()
{
    // Arrange
    var cut = RenderComponent<Counter>();
    cut.Find("p").MarkupMatches("<p>Current count: 0</p>");

    // Act
    var element = cut.Find("button");
    element.Click();

    //Assert
    cut.Find("p").MarkupMatches("<p>Current count: 1</p>");
}
```

And here is another example which includes mocking of service with [JustMock Lite](https://github.com/telerik/JustMockLite)

```
[Fact]
public void TestFetchData_ForecastIsNull()
{
    // Arrange
    var weatherForecastServiceMock = Mock.Create<IWeatherForecastService>();
    Mock.Arrange(() => weatherForecastServiceMock.GetForecastAsync(Arg.IsAny<DateTime>()))
        .Returns(new TaskCompletionSource<WeatherForecast[]>().Task);
    Services.AddSingleton<IWeatherForecastService>(weatherForecastServiceMock);

    // Act
    var cut = RenderComponent<FetchData>();

    // Assert - that it renders the initial loading message
    var initialExpectedHtml = 
                @"<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>
                <p><em>Loading...</em></p>";
    cut.MarkupMatches(initialExpectedHtml);
}
```

The examples are from the blog post [Unit Testing Blazor Components with bUnit and JustMock](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/unit-testing-blazor-components-bunit-justmock)